# SQL Server - Select integer that falls between brackets ( )

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, reverse

HI, how can i select the Integer that falls between a pair of (  ) begining from the right of a cell? Reason being, there might be another pair of brackets containing characters

and what if some records are w/o close brackets for some reason..

```
e.g. 
Period | ProgrammeName             |  
Jan    | ABC (Children) (30)       |
Feb    | Helloworld (20T (20)      |
```

result: 
30
20

i have this script,

select Period, ProgrammeName,
substring(ProgrammeName,(len(ProgrammeName) - (patindex('%(%', Reverse(ProgrammeName)))+2),(len(ProgrammeName)-1))
from Table

but it only displays
30)
20)

i have been manipulating it so that it doesn't extract ')', but can get the expected 
results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty if you want to prep the data for normalization;

```
select substring(fld, patindex('%([0-9]%)', fld) + 1, len(fld) - case patindex('%([0-9]%)', fld) when 0 then 0 else patindex('%([0-9]%)', fld) + 1 end)
```

Comment: can a condition be added such that when there is no ( ), it will be 0?

Comment: `select case when patindex('%([0-9]%)', fld)=0 then '0'
else substring(fld, patindex('%([0-9]%)', fld) + 1, len(fld) - case patindex('%([0-9]%)', fld) when 0 then 0 else patindex('%([0-9]%)', fld) +1 end)
end`

Comment: for some reason, if the record is "ABCDSS(3 (15)", how do i extract 15?

Answer (score 3):

Your database needs normalisation.

Whatever that (30) and (20) represent should be in their own column.

Comment: oh, it's because this is going to be routine uploading. removing manual extraction might be prone to errors..

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this is a migration task. You could try it with a RegEx:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlclr/working-with-regular-expressions)

EDIT: or this blog post

http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html